# Ubuntu as Wifi extender

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan, network-bridge

I'm trying to use my Ubuntu server ( Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) as a wifi extender, but am having problems setting it up.

So I want to connect to the Wifi adapted on my Ubuntu server and all traffic should be routed through the ethernet connection to my gateway and the DHCP should also be assigned by my Gateway Router.

Updated:

I have made some progress, in that the network connections now seem more stable (and the machine boots), the AP comes up, but when I try to connect to it then I don't get an IP address.  So somehow my DHCP is not being passed through to my router/GW.

My current config

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s18:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

  wifis:
    wlan0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        "my-Ap":
          password: "my-password"

  bridges:
   br0:
    optional: true
    dhcp4: no
    dhcp6: no
    addresses: [192.168.178.90/24]
    routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.178.1
    interfaces: [enp6s18,wlan0]
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8]
    parameters:
      stp: true
      forward-delay: 4
```

hostapd

```
country_code=DE
interface=wlan0

bridge=br0


ssid=my-Ap
hw_mode=g
channel=5
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

I have also added iptables rules (which are restored after reboot)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp6s18 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp6s18 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o enp6s18 -j ACCEPT
```

And below is the output from ifconfig

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.90  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::20f:60ff:fe05:a1c0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0f:60:05:a1:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2288  bytes 274980 (274.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 459  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 736  bytes 103313 (103.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:d8ff:fe7e:9ceb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:d8:7e:9c:eb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 811  bytes 122192 (122.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 609  bytes 193105 (193.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp6s18: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e2:3c:44:6d:4f:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2545  bytes 321452 (321.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 918  bytes 113025 (113.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 84  bytes 6352 (6.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84  bytes 6352 (6.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth18d0016: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9470:4fff:feb5:9044  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 96:70:4f:b5:90:44  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 2232 (2.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth44b84e9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9857:36ff:fee3:1c2b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9a:57:36:e3:1c:2b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 70  bytes 41926 (41.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 147  bytes 14528 (14.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth85a1446: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::31:ffff:fed4:7794  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:31:ff:d4:77:94  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 2232 (2.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth8c4fd74: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c48b:8cff:fef9:9e0e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c6:8b:8c:f9:9e:0e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 579  bytes 74864 (74.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 410  bytes 127731 (127.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth93d8067: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c4f9:22ff:fe7c:6af6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c6:f9:22:7c:6a:f6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 39  bytes 2342 (2.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethcc72f4b: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::14b0:3dff:fed4:22a4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 16:b0:3d:d4:22:a4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 2232 (2.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf529f05: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e0f5:1ff:fe83:7dd1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e2:f5:01:83:7d:d1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 40  bytes 3604 (3.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 72  bytes 14240 (14.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0f:60:05:a1:c0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18  bytes 3430 (3.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1387  bytes 114192 (114.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `ifconfig`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Done, also with updated information.  I seem to have taken 2 steps forward and 1 step back and it is still not fully working.

Comment: What version of ubuntu - I *think* newer ones might run nftables, not iptables

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: @JourneymanGeek So I see that it is using "iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)", so then I guess I need to look into that a bit more and find the commands to use!

Comment: Why do you want masquerade? That's L3 functionality, while bridging is L2 functionality. And DHCP won't ever work across a L2 break, as it relies on L2 broadcasts...

Comment: @vidarlo Well as you can probably tell, I don't really know networking!  So then I need help to get this working.

Comment: Try simply removing iptables rules. They should not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I now have it working!

What I done is

1. I started from a fresh install and took it step by step.
2. The netplan config is the same
3. the hostapd config is basically the same (I noticed that my AP name
   was lower case in hostapd and uppercase in netplan, so I changed
   that).
4. I didn't add the IP rules.

And now it seems to basically be working!

The thing is, that during boot it takes about 2 mins to try and configure the networks, before it times out(?) and then finishes booting and comes up.

So I also added `optional: true` to the Ethernet config, and that seems to resolve that issue!